# Formula for Auto Generating number in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to find the way of making a formula that will auto generate the "id" number like we do in mySql auto-generate.

If I explain more, it would be like (number of A1 + 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this formula,

```
=SUM((INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 1)),1)
```

Here `A` is the column.

How it works:

1. You have to put a number on a cell of A column then the very next row of that A column you will put this Formula. Then you should get the number + 1. Which will look like MySql auto generated id.
2. Then you can just grab the blue dot/point of the cell which is lower right of the cell, and expand it to lower of the A column, and it will generate numbers like MySql auto generated id.

Answer (score 0):

use `SEQUENCE`:

```
=SEQUENCE(10)
```

bound to A column:

```
=SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A))
```

Comment: only sequence with the number is working fine, but the next one is not working. Showing some error. Where should I put it? in A2?

Comment: @ShahadatRaiyan if you intend to put it in A column it should be `=SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:B))` or any other column than A that contains data